# Monthly payment using for loop

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying create a program that will let me keep adding a monthly payment for 12 months. This is what I've done so far:

```
for i in range(1,13):     
   print('this is month',i)     
   add = int(input('how much money do you want to add?: '))     
   print(add)
```

Please keep the code simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. In-place addition

   ```
   # start with zero dollars paid at month 1
   add = 0 
   for i in range(1,13):     
       print('this is month',i)     
       month_add = int(input('how much money do you want to add?: '))
       add += month_add

   print(add)
   ```
2. Variable re-assignment:

   ```
   add = 0
   for i in range(1,13):     
       print('this is month',i)     
       month_add = int(input('how much money do you want to add?: '))
       add = add + month_add

   print(add)
   ```
3. Keep track of each month's payment using a `list` and `sum` at the end:

   ```
   # initialize the monthly payment list
   monthly_payments = []
   for i in range(1,13):     
       print('this is month',i)     
       add = int(input('how much money do you want to add?: '))
       monthly_payments.append(add)

   total_paid = sum(monthly_payments)
   print(total_paid)
   ```
4. Use a dictionary to keep track of each month's payment:

   ```
   monthly_payments = {}
   for i in range(1,13):     
       print('this is month',i)     
       add = int(input('how much money do you want to add?: '))
       monthly_payments[i] = add

   total_paid = sum(amount for month, amount in monthly_payments.items())
   print(total_paid)
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Simple!

```
add = 0
for i in range(1,13):     
   print('this is month',i)     
   add += int(input('how much money do you want to add?: '))     
   print(add)
```

Comment: You should really elaborate on this instead of just dumping code; especially considering this looks like homework.